# I want write in a file with relative path

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I want to write "hello" in one file. This is my structure project:

```
home
 src
   Graphics
      indice_corrente.txt
      scrittore.java
```

So in my scrittore.java I do in my code:

```
PrintWriter pw;
try {
    pw = new PrintWriter("indice_corrente.txt");
    pw.write("hello");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I go to open the file I don't read "hello" and the file is empty. In a second moment I need to export this program with a jar, so I need to read the file in a correct way for the jar. Anyone can help me?

Comment: If it's running and not erroring then it is writing to a file _somewhere_. Where is the file being written to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233631/printwriter-destination-issue

Comment: You should consider using absolute paths, as your working directory (which is where `indice_corrente.txt` is currently being written) can change depending on where your run your application.

Comment: @khelwood it saves file in home how can I do to save file in /home/src/grapics/indice_corrente.txt

Comment: Have you tried `new PrintWriter("src/Graphics/indice_corrente.txt")` ?

Comment: Are you running your application in Eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printwriter destination issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233631/printwriter-destination-issue)

Comment: Your structure project (indice_corrente.txt,scrittore.java..) is same after exporting jar ?

Comment: @khelwood thanks your suggest I can write in my file, but when I read what I write, I read  this value  [] and not hello why?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your class `scrittore` the file is created in the current working directory, that looking at your directory tree is in the home of your project.

I also suppose you're running your class `scrittore` some kind of IDE, like Eclipse.

Have a look at home of your project and see if there is a `indice_corrente.txt` created there.